# 2d / multidimensional array char

Tags: arrays, replace, char, 2d

Here is my code

```
     #include <stdio.h>
     #include <string.h>
     #include <stdlib.h>

 int main ()
 {




 int i,k;
 char a[4][2] = { {'*','*'}, {'*','*'}, {'*','*'}, {'*','*'}};


 /* output each array element's value */
 for ( i = 0; i < 4; i++ ) {

  for ( k = 0; k < 2; k++ ) {
     printf("%c ", a[i][k] );
  }
  printf("\n");
  }
  return 0;
  }
```

I would like to know how to replace a character from a 2d array with another character with user input? for example if the user wants to replace the asterisk at [0][0] with an F the output would look like this:

```
         F *
         * *
         * *
         * *
  `
```

I would really appreciate it because I can't seem to find any example of this anywhere. Thanks

Comment: hehe I think I got it :D thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
int main ()
{

    int i,k,row,column;
    char a[4][2] = { {'*','*'}, {'*','*'}, {'*','*'}, {'*','*'}},rc;

    // before replace
    printf("Before Replace :\n");
    for ( i = 0; i < 4; i++ ) {
        for ( k = 0; k < 2; k++ ) {
            printf("%c ", a[i][k] );
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("Enter a Character you want to Replace : ");
    scanf("%c",&rc);

    printf("Enter row and column Index: ");
    scanf("%d%d",&row,&column);

    for ( i = 0; i < 4; i++ ) {
        for ( k = 0; k < 2; k++ ) {
               if(i==row && k==column){
                    a[i][k]=rc;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("\nAfter replace :\n");
    for ( i = 0; i < 4; i++ ) {
        for ( k = 0; k < 2; k++ ) {
            printf("%c ", a[i][k] );
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```